# Graphs in android via php script

Tags: php, android

I want to make a feature in my android that will generate graphs for example yearly basis. Is there anyway to generate graphs via php scripts. Hope you can share some tutorials or links that will help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you generated the graphs in HTML and CSS via PHP you could display them in a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) (essentially just a browser window to incorporate HTML into an app). I've attached the tutorial